# Is it secure to let a cookie be encrypted by a client public key?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, oauth

I am thinking about a stateless authentication service "myloginservice.io" which is supposed to enable simple login with github, reddit, twitter with etc. using predefined accounts for the respective auth strategy.
This service will be targeted at demos, playgrounds and should not be a serious alternative to auth0 and similiar service. It should be safe enough though.

The workflow should be as follows:

- from "yourwebsite.com" login via link to https://myloginservice.io/reddit?pubkey=YOUR_PUBKEY&domain=YOUR_TOPLEVEL_DOMAIN&successRedirect=YOUR_SUCCESS_URL&failureRedirect=YOUR_FAILURE_URL
- myloginservice.com does the authentication and stores the user encrypted with the public key provided via query params (also setting the cookie domain)
- myloginservice.com redirects to YOUR_SUCCESS_URL/YOUR_FAILURE_URL
- "yourwebsite.com" decrypts the user cookie and does whatever is appropriate

As the public key is visible, anyone could create and manually set the session from debug console. But it would be pointless without real user data...isn't it?

Are the any security concerns?

Comment: Pointless is re-inventing the wheel. What you want already exists, and is called OpenID.

Comment: the public key on the client side is same for all users?

Comment: Everyone using the service needs to create a key pair.

Comment: Has a user to create an OpenID account upfront? I have not yet seen any service providing login with OpenID. Also the optional "accessTokens" (like for GitHub) should be available to subsequently use the respective service.